# Maven HeuristicMixedException with Wildfly webapp

Tags: java, maven, wildfly

If I try to compile my webapp with `mvn clean install -U` I get the errorlog below.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< com.mycompany:myproject >---------------------
[INFO] Building mycompany.com Scheduler 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 19 source files to /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/src/main/java/controller/Delete.java:[10,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HeuristicMixedException
  location: package javax.transaction
[ERROR] /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/src/main/java/controller/Delete.java:[11,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HeuristicRollbackException
  location: package javax.transaction
[ERROR] /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/src/main/java/controller/Delete.java:[12,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class NotSupportedException
  location: package javax.transaction
[ERROR] /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/src/main/java/controller/Delete.java:[13,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RollbackException
  location: package javax.transaction
[ERROR] /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/src/main/java/controller/Delete.java:[14,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SystemException
  location: package javax.transaction
[ERROR] /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/src/main/java/controller/Delete.java:[15,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UserTransaction
  location: package javax.transaction
[ERROR] /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/src/main/java/controller/Delete.java:[31,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UserTransaction
  location: class controller.Delete<T>
[ERROR] /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/src/main/java/controller/Delete.java:[77,49] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class NotSupportedException
  location: class controller.Delete<T>
[ERROR] /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/src/main/java/controller/Delete.java:[77,72] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SystemException
  location: class controller.Delete<T>
[ERROR] /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/src/main/java/controller/Delete.java:[78,36] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RollbackException
  location: class controller.Delete<T>
[ERROR] /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/src/main/java/controller/Delete.java:[78,55] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HeuristicMixedException
  location: class controller.Delete<T>
[ERROR] /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/src/main/java/controller/Delete.java:[78,80] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HeuristicRollbackException
  location: class controller.Delete<T>

...

[INFO] 36 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.186 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-10T13:50:37+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project myproject: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/src/main/java/controller/Delete.java:[10,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class HeuristicMixedException
[ERROR]   location: package javax.transaction
[ERROR] /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/src/main/java/controller/Delete.java:[11,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class HeuristicRollbackException
[ERROR]   location: package javax.transaction
[ERROR] /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/src/main/java/controller/Delete.java:[12,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class NotSupportedException
[ERROR]   location: package javax.transaction
[ERROR] /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/src/main/java/controller/Delete.java:[13,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class RollbackException
[ERROR]   location: package javax.transaction
[ERROR] /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/src/main/java/controller/Delete.java:[14,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class SystemException
[ERROR]   location: package javax.transaction
[ERROR] /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/src/main/java/controller/Delete.java:[15,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class UserTransaction
[ERROR]   location: package javax.transaction
[ERROR] /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/src/main/java/controller/Delete.java:[31,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class UserTransaction
[ERROR]   location: class controller.Delete<T>
[ERROR] /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/src/main/java/controller/Delete.java:[77,49] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class NotSupportedException
[ERROR]   location: class controller.Delete<T>
[ERROR] /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/src/main/java/controller/Delete.java:[77,72] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class SystemException
[ERROR]   location: class controller.Delete<T>
[ERROR] /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/src/main/java/controller/Delete.java:[78,36] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class RollbackException
[ERROR]   location: class controller.Delete<T>
[ERROR] /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/src/main/java/controller/Delete.java:[78,55] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class HeuristicMixedException
[ERROR]   location: class controller.Delete<T>
[ERROR] /home/user/workspace JavaEE/myproject/src/main/java/controller/Delete.java:[78,80] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class HeuristicRollbackException
[ERROR]   location: class controller.Delete<T>

...

[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

The `pom.xml` content is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source Copyright 2013, Red Hat, Inc. 
    and/or its affiliates, and individual contributors by the @authors tag. See 
    the copyright.txt in the distribution for a full listing of individual contributors. 
    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not 
    use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy 
    of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required 
    by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the 
    License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS 
    OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific 
    language governing permissions and limitations under the License. -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mycompany</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>mycompany.com application</name>
    <description>A starter Java EE 7 webapp project for use on JBoss WildFly / WildFly, generated from the jboss-javaee6-webapp archetype</description>

    <url>http://wildfly.org</url>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <properties>
        <!-- Explicitly declaring the source encoding eliminates the following 
            message: -->
        <!-- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered 
            resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->
        <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>1.0.2.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>

        <!-- Define the version of the JBoss BOMs we want to import to specify 
            tested stacks. -->
        <version.jboss.bom>8.2.1.Final</version.jboss.bom>

        <!-- other plugin versions -->
        <version.compiler.plugin>3.1</version.compiler.plugin>
        <version.surefire.plugin>2.16</version.surefire.plugin>
        <version.war.plugin>2.5</version.war.plugin>

        <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 7 APIs including a Bill 
                of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or a collection) 
                of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct versions 
                of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools stack (you can 
                read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 7 APIs, with some extras tools 
                for your project, such as Arquillian for testing) and the jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate 
                stack you can read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 7 APIs, with extras 
                from the Hibernate family of projects) -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- First declare the APIs we depend on and need for compilation. All 
            of them are provided by JBoss WildFly -->

        <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250), we use provided scope 
            as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the JAX-RS API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
            in JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
        <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
        <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Now we declare any tools needed -->

        <!-- Annotation processor to generate the JPA 2.0 metamodel classes for 
            typesafe criteria queries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Annotation processor that raising compilation errors whenever constraint 
            annotations are incorrectly used. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Needed for running tests (you may also use TestNG) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Optional, but highly recommended -->
        <!-- Arquillian allows you to test enterprise code such as EJBs and Transactional(JTA) 
            JPA from JUnit/TestNG -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- Maven will append the version to the finalName (which is the name 
            given to the generated war, and hence the context root) -->
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Java EE 7 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- The WildFly plugin deploys your war to a local WildFly container -->
            <!-- To use, run: mvn package wildfly:deploy -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- The default profile skips all tests, though you can tune it to run 
                just unit tests based on a custom pattern -->
            <!-- Seperate profiles are provided for running all tests, including Arquillian 
                tests that execute in the specified container -->
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>

            <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests in your 
                WildFly instance -->
            <!-- This profile will start a new WildFly instance, and execute the test, 
                shutting it down when done -->
            <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-wildfly-managed -->
            <id>arq-wildfly-managed</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests in a remote 
                WildFly instance -->
            <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-wildfly-remote -->
            <id>arq-wildfly-remote</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when 
                invoking mvn. -->
            <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
                will need. -->
            <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'deployments' 
                folder. -->
            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                            <warName>ROOT</warName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
</project>
```

The code for the Delete.java source is

```
package controller;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException;
import javax.transaction.HeuristicRollbackException;
import javax.transaction.NotSupportedException;
import javax.transaction.RollbackException;
import javax.transaction.SystemException;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

import model.EntityType;
import service.LogService;

/** class for deleting SINGLE entities */
public abstract class Delete<T extends EntityType> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5315202645032974752L;

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction ta;

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    /**
     * {@link EntityManager} might be necessary in
     * {@link #removeForeignEntities(EntityType)}
     *
     * @return {@link EntityManager}
     */
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * configure targeted face
     *
     * @return String null (no redirection per default)
     */
    protected String redirect() {
        return null;
    }

    /** remove foreign entities from entity {@link T} */
    protected void removeForeignEntities(final T entity) {
        // remove
    }

    /**
     * delete entity by adding selected record in JSF
     *
     * <div>e.g.:
     *
     * <pre>
     * <code>
     * &lt;h:commandButton action="#{activityDelete.delete(item)}" /&gt;
     * </code>
     * </pre>
     *
     * </div>
     *
     * @return {@link #redirect()}
     */
    public String delete(final T entity) throws NotSupportedException, SystemException, SecurityException,
            IllegalStateException, RollbackException, HeuristicMixedException, HeuristicRollbackException {
        LogService.getLogger(this).info(new StringBuffer("delete(T): ").append(entity).toString());
        ta.begin();
        // type safety already fulfilled by definition <T extends EntityType>
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final T deleteEntity = (T) entityManager.find(entity.getClass(), entity.getId());
        removeForeignEntities(deleteEntity);
        entityManager.remove(deleteEntity);
        ta.commit();
        return redirect();
    }

}
```

and for EntityType.java is

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * This bean is necessary to inject the entity to the CRUD beans.
 *
 * This must not be an interface or an abstract class since its not supported
 * for the ORM (JBoss) implementation.
 *
 *
 * console warning
 *
 * <pre>
 * console warning "Multiple beans are eligible for injection to the injection point"
 * </pre>
 *
 * Eclipse IDE error
 *
 * <pre>
 * Multiple markers at this line
    - Multiple beans are eligible for injection to the injection point [JSR-346
     §5.2.2]
    - Injection point type cannot be a type variable [JSR-346 §5.2.3]
 * </pre>
 */
public class EntityType implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6260606086182547955L;

    public EntityType() {
        // default constructor
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

I guess I can solve this problem with changing `<version.compiler.plugin>3.1</version.compiler.plugin` to `<version.compiler.plugin>3.6</version.compiler.plugin` or `<version.compiler.plugin>3.6.0</version.compiler.plugin` but both gives the same results.

What do I misunderstand and what is here the solution to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. Once I added the transaction api manually in "Eclipse IDE" in the "Java Build Path" register.

[image]

I added to the `pom.xml` the dependency for the right api.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.3_spec</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

within the `project/dependencies` node.

Executing the command `mvn clean install compile -U` results to

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.363 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-10T16:10:26+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and can be deployed to the wildfly server.

P.S.: I also removed the jboss-transaction-api_1.3_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar from the "Java Build Path" before executing the command.